# Start-Job connecting to Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I need to run parallel Search-Mailbox cmdlets against 100's mailboxes to delete the content but they need to fit certain parameters first like certain CAS protocols enabled and a forwarding address present. I've also parameterised it so I can pass a $maxJobCount int to it so the runner can specify a maximum number of concurrently running jobs to allow so as to account for resources on their machine.

Got the thing working then got to the start-job component which is a pretty simple function.

```
function _StartJob {
    param (
        $mailAddress
    )
    Start-Job -Name $mailAddress -Scriptblock { 
        Get-EXOMailbox $mailAddress -PropertySets Delivery 
    }
}
```

That's returning an error saying I need to run Connect-ExchangeOnline before using the cmdlets which is where I learned script blocks in Start-Job are actually new PowerShell.exe processes so don't inherit modules and session options.

Does anyone know an easier way around this? In an MFA environment, it either means sitting there and pasting the password in a few hundred times or convincing the Change board and Secops dept to let me setup a graph application with delete rights... both painful

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass in the creds into the block however you want.

```
$kvCertName = 'Cert'
#I am using azure automation here to get the cert its different for keyvault
$kvCertPFX = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $kvCertName
$tenantid = 'yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com'
$appid = '00000000-46da-6666-5555-33333cfe77ec'
$startDate = ([datetime]::Today).AddDays(-7)

#Build the script block
$block = {
    Param(
        $kvCert,
        $appID,
        $tenantID,
        $n,
        $startdate
    )
    $newCertPFX = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($kvCert)
    Connect-ExchangeOnline -Certificate ([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$newCertPFX) -AppID $appID -Organization $tenantID -ErrorAction Stop
    Search-AdminAuditLog -StartDate $startDate.adddays($n) -EndDate $($startDate.AddDays($n) | get-date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59) -ExternalAccess:$false -ResultSize 250000
    Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -confirm:$false
}


#Remove all jobs created
Get-Job | Remove-Job


#Run All the Parrallel Jobs
$num = 0..6
$kvCert = $kvCertPFX.Export(3)
foreach($n in $num){Start-Job -Scriptblock $Block -ArgumentList @($kvCert,$appID,$tenantid,$n,$startdate)}


#Wait for all jobs to finish.
do {start-sleep 1}
until ($(Get-Job -State Running).count -eq 0)


#Get information from each job.
$adminPowerShellAuditLog = $null
foreach($job in Get-Job){$adminPowerShellAuditLog+= Receive-Job -Id ($job.Id)}

Write-Output $adminPowerShellAuditLog
```